# Force disabled scrolling when model opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've been trying to disable the scrolling when modal opened

```
$(document).on('show.bs.modal', '#setting', function (e) {


    $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
    $("body").css("overflow-y", "hidden");
    $("body").css("overflow-x", "hidden");

    console.log('%c SUPREME ', 'background: red; color: white;');


});
```

The console seems to run, but the scroll codes not seem to works - it still happening.

Link = https://mybabies.app/baby/3b1344de-1d91-4c5c-b289-572d7e779c5f?code=!taly

[image]

How do I make sure this not happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you can hide the scrollbar by changing the body height using:

```
$('body').height(0)
```

And to undo it when you want to close the modal you can use

```
$('body').height('auto')
```

For more info check:
https://api.jquery.com/height/

Answer (score 1):

Could you try adding `overflow: hidden` to the `<html>` tag? It's working fine for me on Firefox.

*Sorry I post this as an answer, I don't have enough reputation to comment.*

Comment: No problem @cyb3rZ